# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when not fond the record i nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want find record and update the the record in mongoose and nodejs .

```
  async DeleteRole(req, res, next) {
    let validationData = await this.ValidationAction(req, res);
    if (validationData[0]) {
      Role.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: { isDelete: true } },
        { useFindAndModify: false },
        (error, role)=> {
          console.log(role)
          if (error) next(error);
          if (!role) return res.status(200).send({
            message: "NotFoundRecord",
            statusCode: 200,
            success: false,
          });
        }
      );
       return res.status(200).send({
        message: "Success",
        statusCode: 200,
        success: true,
      });
    }
     return res.status(200).send({
      message: "BadREquest",
      statusCode: 400,
      success: false,
    });
  }
```

i want when record not found it show me the errro the record not found and somve one else .

but when i send a request it show me this error :

> F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:19
> throw error;
> ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:533:11)
at ServerResponse.header (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at RoleController.Notfound (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\src\http\controller\BaseController.js:26:28)
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\src\http\controller\RoleController.js:25:34
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4882:16
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4882:16
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4882:16
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4905:21
at F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4382:18
at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3462:12)
at model.Query. (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3037:8)
at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (F:\Projects\Nodejs\SalesSignal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:

**now i want tow things : A => find the best way for find and update record and solve this problem ? how can i solve this problem ??? **

Comment: Doesn't `Role.findByIdAndUpdate` return a promise so that you could use `await` there as well?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `else` statement or a `return` at the `next(error)` call, and also the code that sends the `Success` message doesn't wait for the `findByIdAndUpdate` to finish - it always sends the response before anything else.

```
async DeleteRole(req, res, next) {
  let validationData = await this.ValidationAction(req, res);
  if (validationData[0]) {
    Role.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      $set: { isDelete: true }
    }, { useFindAndModify: false }, (error, role)=> {
      if (error) {
        next(error);
      } else if (!role) {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "NotFoundRecord",
          statusCode: 200,
          success: false,
        });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "Success",
          statusCode: 200,
          success: true,
        })
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "BadREquest",
      statusCode: 400,
      success: false,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @kianoushdortaj Please post the code of `RoleController.Notfound` then (and the code that is using it). Probably you have similar problems elsewhere.